# How to wrap DOM keywords in a span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, nodes

I am writing a JavaScript script that will walk the `DOM` and wrap a specific keyword in a `<span>` tag. I want my `script` to wrap any occurrences of the word `pan` in a `<span>` so I can style it using `<span style='color: red'`. I don't actually want to use the word, `pan`, I am just using it as an example.

I have already reviewed many similar posts here, but none of them solve my problem. Most are either nuclear, over-complicated and confusing, or over-simplified and do not work as I've intended.

Here is what I have written so far:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>My <span style='font-weight: bold'>favorite</span> kitchen item is the pan.</p>
    <p>A pan can also be used as a weapon.</p>
    <script>
      // walk the document body
      function walk (node) {
        // if text node
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
          // will always be an element
          const parent = node.parentNode;
          
          // ignore script and style tags
          const tagName = parent.tagName;
          if (tagName !== 'SCRIPT' && tagName !== 'STYLE') {
            
            // wrap occurrences of 'pan' in a red `<span>` tag
            const span = '<span style="color: red">pan</span>';
            parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace (/pan/g, span)
          }
        }
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
          walk (node);
          node = node.nextSibling;
        }
      }
      walk (document.body)
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code runs as intended most of the time. However, in this example, it doesn't. If you were to run this code, [this](https://i.ibb.co/B60wXT1/result.png) would be the result.

I know what is causing this. However, I have no idea how to resolve it.

Two of the text nodes, `My` and `kitchen item is the pan.` have a parent element with the following `innerHTML`: `My <span style="font-weight: bold">favorite</span> kitchen item is the pan.` The "pan" in `<span>` is being replaced, and is causing the problem.

If I use `parentNode.textContent` instead of `parentNode.innerHTML`, it does not wrap it in a `<span>` tag, it inserts it as visible text.

I understand this could be fixed by changing `/pan/g` to `/\bpan\b/g`, but that only fixes this example I created. I need the `<span>` tag to be only inserted into text content, and not tag names or other HTML.

What should I do?

Comment: `tagName !== 'script' || tagName !== 'style'` That condition will always be `true`.

Comment: @ziggywiggy Whoops, I'll fix that.

Comment: @TylerRoper Fixed. Thanks! I know what went wrong, I was just writing this example quickly to demonstrate what was going wrong without sharing a massive script.

Comment: is your problem solved ? or you still need an answer !

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil No, it hasn't been solved yet. That was just a minor error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search a given `htmlString` with an escaped search string. Doing so (with appropriate escaping) will help avoid problems like matching HTML tags (ex. `<s`**pan**`>`) or substrings (ex. **Pan**dora).

```js
/*
highlight(selector, string)
@ Params:
  selector [String]: Same syntax as CSS/jQuery selector
  string   [String]: Seach string
*/
// A: Get the htmlString of the target's content
// B: Escape the search string
// C: Create a RegExp Object of the escaped search string
// D: Find and replace all matches with match wrapped in a <mark>
// E: Remove original HTML
// F: Insert new HTML
function highlight(selector, string) {
  let dom = document.querySelector(selector);
  let str = dom.innerHTML; //A
  let esc = `(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\\/a>))\\b(${string})\\b`; //B
  let rgx = new RegExp(esc, "gi"); //C
  let txt = str.replace(rgx, `<mark>$1</mark>`); //D
  dom.replaceChildren(); //E 
  dom.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', txt); //F
}

highlight('body', "pan");
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>My <span style='font-weight: bold'>favorite</span> kitchen item is the pan.</p>
  <p>A pan can also be used as a weapon.</p>
  <p>Pan was the Greek god of the wild.</p>
  <p>Eboli was breifly a pandemic threat.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, that actually works very well. Thank you! I'm a bit confused about the RegEx, would you mind elaborating? It reminds me of a similar one I wrote: `/<[^]*?<\/[^]*?>/g`.

Comment: Hi @KadenCampbell `[^<]` is a class that excludes any number `+` of `<` followed by `>` *OR* `|` an exclusion class `[^>]+` of  any number of `>` followed by a link end tag `<\\/a>`. All of that is wrapped in a negative lookahead `(?!`...`)` which means that whatever is followed by `(?!`...`)` should be ignored.  `\\b(${string})\\b` isolates the search string with `\\b` boundary meta sequences which are indicators of the start/end of a non-word and a word.

Comment: This entirely removes and reinserts the html in the body... which causes things to stop working (tested in a react app) ... any other option that does not replace the whole thing?

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva yes I agree, it's line E. `dom.innerHTML = ''` has been replaced with `dom.replaceChildren()`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: BTW, `dom.innerHTML` on line A reads the HTML and line F `.insertAdjacentHTML()` adds HTML safely. As for it removing HTML on `<body>`, I made the function as agnostic as possible, so any element can be targeted. If there's still a problem, let me know I just thought of a possible alternative.

Comment: @zer00ne `replaceChildren` still breaks the click events for my react website :/ thanks for the help though

Comment: @JahirFiquitiva IOC, that's no problem. Use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56194735/2813224)