# HTML removing and adding event listeners

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a series of details HTML elements, all of which I want to toggle open when one is toggled. The  elements each look something like this:

```
<details class="basic" data-target="basic">
     <summary>Click me 1</summary>
     Some descriptive text 1
<details>
```

I add an event listener on the toggle event of every  element:

```js
addEventListeners();

function addEventListeners(){ 

      var deets = document.getElementsByTagName("details");
      for(var i = 0; i < deets.length; i++){     
           deets[i].addEventListener("toggle", togGroups, false);
      }

 }

function togGroups(event){
    
    var targetClass = this.getAttribute("data-target"),
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClass),
    open = this.open; //currently open or not?

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){ 
        let el = elements[i];
        
        //Remove the event listener to stop triggering
        //the toggle event when setting every element's "open"
        //status
        el.removeEventListener("toggle", togGroups, false);
        el.open = open;
    }    

    //Scroll the originally-toggled element into view
    this.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start'
    });

    //Re-add event listeners for the next toggle
    addEventListeners();

}
```

This code works to open all of my  elements, but I cannot figure how how to get it to scroll to the originally toggled element. Instead, it scrolls to the last toggled element -- basically, the bottom of the page. I think that behavior would make sense if no event listener were removed in the for .. loop — the toggle event for every  element would be fired every time the "open" property is set to true, so the function would fire many times and eventually "this" would be the last element. However, I'm trying to remove it and then re-set it only after every element has been opened.

Incidentally, if I remove the final addEventListeners() line, it scrolls correctly, but then I lose the ability to click again.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Many thanks.

Comment: `addEventListeners();` adds listeners to each of the elements every time `togGroups` is called. These, as the name says, **add** to the event listeners already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need to remove any event listeners nor do we need one bound to each `<details>`. All we need is a single event listener registered to an ancestor tag* for an unlimited number of descendant tags.

Details are commented in demo. Further details are also in the `<details>`.
*<sub>***it can even be window or document, but not recommended unless it's for key events***</sub>

```js
// Reference <main>
const main = document.querySelector('main');

// Register <main> to click event -- fire callback
main.addEventListener('click', callback);

// Callback pass the Event Object
function callback(event) {
  // Prevent <details> from toggling it's own [open]
  event.preventDefault();
  // Reference the clicked tag
  const tgt = event.target;
  // Collect all <details> into a NodeList
  const dtl = document.querySelectorAll('details');
  // Iterate through NodeList -- on each <details> toggle [open]
  for (let detail of dtl) {
    detail.toggleAttribute('open');
  }
  // Scroll clicked tag into center view
  tgt.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'center'
  });
  // Terminate function
  return false;
}
```

```css
:root {
  font: 400 16px/1.2 Arial
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

main {
  padding: 40vh 0;
}

details {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-bottom: 4px ridge #444;
  border-top: 4px ridge #444;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px
}

details:focus-within {
  outline: 3px solid cyan;
}

summary {
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 5px ridge #444;
  border-left: 5px ridge #444;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <details>
    <summary>Read More...</summary>
    Register an event to an ancestor tag that all targeted tags share in common. In this demo that ancestor tag is <code>&lt;main&gt;</code>.
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>Further Details</summary>
    Write the callback function so that it only reacts to events triggered on specific tags (ie <code>&lt;details&gt;</code>) and ignore the rest. This is possible because the click event propigates (or bubbles).
  </details>

  <details>
    <summary>Code Description</summary>
    This programming pattern is called Event Delegation.
  </details>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add the vent listeners once..

```
 addEventListeners();

  function addEventListeners() {
    var deets = document.getElementsByTagName("details");
    for(var i = 0; i < deets.length; i++){
      deets[i].addEventListener("toggle", togGroups, false);
    }
  }

  function togGroups(event) {
    var targetClass = this.getAttribute("data-target");
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(targetClass);

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      let el = elements[i];
      el.open = this.open;
    }

    // Scroll the originally-toggled element into view
    this.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'start'
    });
  }
```